# Website problems with Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, xhtml, safari

Does anyone know why my site is all messed up on safari? I need to get it live by monday and this is racking my brain.

http://cheapramen.com/JQuery/WildFire/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the most obvious problem, I believe you need to have `float:left;` on the image so that the text lines up properly.

I don't see anything else that looks unintentional; can you clarify what you'd like fixed?

Also, please [validate your site](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fcheapramen.com%2FJQuery%2FWildFire%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) before asking for help fixing it.

Comment: word up, sorry I just switched from CSE to notepad++ and I totally spaced on the doctype and did not validate. Thanks for the tip, hopefully I get er' goin.

Comment: I floated the picture of the bar left as well as the other content and now it is perfect in all browsers! You rule! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When I look at the page source, I see a closing script tag without a corresponding opening tag right after the body tag. Do you have some conditional code that should contain the closing tag?

```
<body>



</script>
```

Comment: ooo thank you, an old tag I forgot to delete, still have crazy formatting problems though....

Comment: your last image tag is also not closed

Answer (score 0):

I would give it a DocType and so forth.

Do run it on [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fcheapramen.com%2FJQuery%2FWildFire%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) from time to time. It should validate and, everything that does not validate, you should know why.

Meaning that what does not validate is under-your-control and you know why it doesn't.